# How can i send data from MainActivity to Viewmodel, data is not displayed

Tags: android, android-fragments, model-view

I'm relative new to Android programming and read a few things about ViewModel, Fragments.
What i'm trying is to create an app with a few fragments. It needs to be able to send data from the MainActivity to different fragments and from the Fragments back to the Main activity.

I am able to send data from the main activity to the Fragment page but I am not able to use the ModelView and use that in combination with an observer.

For this example I used the basic project in Android Studio with the Navigation Drawer Views Activity.

MainActivity:

```
package com.example.eriksslider

import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.Menu
import androidx.activity.viewModels
import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar
import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
import androidx.navigation.findNavController
import androidx.navigation.ui.AppBarConfiguration
import androidx.navigation.ui.navigateUp
import androidx.navigation.ui.setupActionBarWithNavController
import androidx.navigation.ui.setupWithNavController
import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.fragment.app.viewModels
import com.example.eriksslider.databinding.ActivityMainBinding
import com.example.eriksslider.ui.home.HomeFragment
import com.example.eriksslider.ui.home.HomeViewModel

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var appBarConfiguration: AppBarConfiguration
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    private val viewModel: HomeViewModel by viewModels()

    val homeFragment = HomeFragment()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        setSupportActionBar(binding.appBarMain.toolbar)

        binding.appBarMain.fab.setOnClickListener { view ->
            viewModel.setText("Hallo")
            homeFragment.test("Hallo")
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                .setAction("Action", null).show()
        }
        val drawerLayout: DrawerLayout = binding.drawerLayout
        val navView: NavigationView = binding.navView
        val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_main)
        // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
        // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
        appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(
            setOf(
                R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_gallery, R.id.nav_slideshow
            ), drawerLayout
        )
        setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
        navView.setupWithNavController(navController)
    }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu)
        return true
    }

    override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
        val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_main)
        return navController.navigateUp(appBarConfiguration) || super.onSupportNavigateUp()
    }
}
```

Home Fragment:

```
package com.example.eriksslider.ui.home

import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.fragment.app.viewModels
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider
import com.example.eriksslider.databinding.FragmentHomeBinding

class HomeFragment : Fragment() {

    private var _binding: FragmentHomeBinding? = null

    // This property is only valid between onCreateView and
    // onDestroyView.
    private val binding get() = _binding!!

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        val homeViewModel =
            ViewModelProvider(this)[HomeViewModel::class.java]

        _binding = FragmentHomeBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        val root: View = binding.root

        val textView: TextView = binding.textView2
        homeViewModel.text.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
            textView.text = it
        }
        return root
    }

    override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
        _binding = null
    }

    fun test(value: String){
        Log.d("Home Fragment", value)
    }
}
```

And the modelview:

```
package com.example.eriksslider.ui.home

import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData
import androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel

class HomeViewModel : ViewModel() {

    private val _text = MutableLiveData<String>()
    val text: LiveData<String> = _text

    fun setText(value: String){
        _text.value = value
    }
}
```

fragment_home file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.home.HomeFragment">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_home"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/text_home"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="175dp" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

If i look at the Logcat i can see when i press the button that the data is sent to the HomeFragment and that's basiclyit. The TextView is not updated at all. My question is this post is, how can I get the data sent from MainActivity displayed on the Home Fragment page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the fragment is creating a new HomeViewModel. To get a view model from an activity, use `activityViewModels` delegation.

MainActivity

```kotlin
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var appBarConfiguration: AppBarConfiguration
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    private val viewModel: HomeViewModel by viewModels()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        setSupportActionBar(binding.appBarMain.toolbar)

        binding.appBarMain.fab.setOnClickListener { view ->
            viewModel.setText("Hallo")
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                .setAction("Action", null).show()
        }
        val drawerLayout: DrawerLayout = binding.drawerLayout
        val navView: NavigationView = binding.navView
        val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_main)
        // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
        // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
        appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(
            setOf(
                R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_gallery, R.id.nav_slideshow
            ), drawerLayout
        )
        setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
        navView.setupWithNavController(navController)
    }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu)
        return true
    }

    override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
        val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_main)
        return navController.navigateUp(appBarConfiguration) || super.onSupportNavigateUp()
    }
}
```

HomeFragment

```kotlin
class HomeFragment : Fragment() {
    private var _binding: FragmentHomeBinding? = null
    private val binding get() = _binding!!

    private val homeViewModel by activityViewModels<HomeViewModel>()

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        _binding = FragmentHomeBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        val root: View = binding.root

        val textView: TextView = binding.textView2
        homeViewModel.text.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
            textView.text = it
        }
        return root
    }

    override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
        _binding = null
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply. The give solution does trigger an error: 
`FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                                    Process: com.example.eriksslider, PID: 31617
                                                                                                    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment HomeFragment{8ae0153} (9230dcdd-fdda-4851-872c-0f2884d8882e) not attached to an activity.`

Comment: It is because you are creating manually HomeFragment in MainActivity. Delete `val homeFragment = HomeFragment()` line.

Comment: How do I then pass the "Hello" from MainActivity to the HomeFragment? 
I tried to use the viewModel.setText but that one doesnt work.
Whats the way to call an function in the HomeFragment to set the value in ViewModel, or do i need to pass the value directly to the ViewModel?

Comment: @Lithium use `setText` function you defined in MainActivity, then get the view model from MainActivity in HomeFragment with `activityViewModels` and observe LiveData.

Comment: I have a hard time to see the fault. I now have the `private val homeViewModel by activityViewModels<HomeViewModel>()` in my HomeFragment and in MainActivity I use: `private val viewModel: HomeViewModel by viewModels()` to call the function in the HomeFragment file.

Would you mind to post some code? I should forget something.

Answer (score 0):

To test a bit more I added a button to the HomeFragment and trigger it on a click. Then call the test function to change the textview data. That works but when sending data from the MainActivity the error comes up.

The HomeFragment is now like:

```
package com.example.eriksslider.ui.home

import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.activity.viewModels
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.fragment.app.activityViewModels
import androidx.fragment.app.viewModels
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider
import com.example.eriksslider.databinding.FragmentHomeBinding

class HomeFragment : Fragment() {

    private var _binding: FragmentHomeBinding? = null

    // This property is only valid between onCreateView and
    // onDestroyView.
    private val binding get() = _binding!!
    private val homeViewModel by activityViewModels<HomeViewModel>()

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        val homeViewModel =
            ViewModelProvider(this)[HomeViewModel::class.java]

        _binding = FragmentHomeBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        val root: View = binding.root
        binding.button.setOnClickListener { test("Button pressed") }
        val textView: TextView = binding.textView2
        homeViewModel.text.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
            textView.text = it
        }
        return root
    }

    override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
        _binding = null
    }

    fun test(value: String){
        Log.d("Home Fragment", value)
        homeViewModel.setText(value)
    }
}
```

When using the old viewModel val: `private val viewModel: HomeViewModel by viewModels()`
We get this error when we try to send something from the MainActivity: `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't access ViewModels from detached fragment`